# Passing multiple parameters via a <s:url/> Struts2 tag

Tags: java, ajax, struts2, parameter-passing

This code should send two parameters to the struts action:

```
<s:url id="loadReportsForAPageInitial" value="/loadReportsForAPage.action" >
    <s:param name="reportsCount_hidden" value="3"></s:param>
    <s:param name="pageNumber_hidden" value="1"></s:param>
</s:url>
<sj:div href="%{loadReportsForAPageInitial}">
</sj:div>
```

the problem is only the first parameter's value is sent to the struts action and the second one is null! I changed the place of two parameters and again only the first one was fine.

Is it possible to pass more than one parameter via a s:url tag?

**UPDATE**

this is how the url tag is rendered:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    var options_div_1179027906 = {};
    options_div_1179027906.jqueryaction = "container";
    options_div_1179027906.id = "div_1179027906";
    options_div_1179027906.href = "/FAP/loadReportsForAPage.action";
    options_div_1179027906.hrefparameter = "reportsCount_hidden=3&amp;pageNumber_hidden=1";
    jQuery.struts2_jquery.bind(jQuery('#div_1179027906'),options_div_1179027906);

});
```

Comment: How does the url render? Also note that using "id" for the url var is deprecated.

Comment: @DaveNewton : I added the render result up there, does the problem have anything to do with the "&amp" at the end of first parameter?

Comment: You're actually asking the wrong question--yes, you can pass more than one parameter via the `<s:url>` tag, but the real question regards the `<sj:div>` tag and how it handles parameters--it looks like it's escaping it. I think you're correct that this is the issue.

Comment: So it seems to be a Struts2jQuery plugin's bug, interesting!

Comment: Don't know if it's a bug or intended behavior; I'd check the source first to see how it fills `hrefparameter`. In the meantime, it could be worked around in a variety of ways, by doing minimal parsing/splitting of a single parameter, if the source yields no clues.

Comment: well, yeah I did pass a single comma delimitered param to get the work go on. I think I'd better consult with the plugin's developers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may disable the URL escape behavior using `escapeAmp="false"` attribute. By default, this is enabled, so URL parameter `&` will render `&amp;`. This will cause a problem on reading the parameter value with parameter name.

1. You may need to read the parameter, 
   `request.getParameter("amp;pageNumber_hidden")`
2. You have stop escaping the entities by adding attribute `escapeAmp`
   and set the value false as part of the `<s:url>` tag (Recommended)

---

```
<s:url id="loadReportsForAPageInitial"
       value="/loadReportsForAPage.action" 
       escapeAmp="false">
```